# How to assign an array in JavaScript variable passed from spring controller?

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have an array that passed from spring controller to view in thymleaf template.but when I am trying to assign it in a javascript variable it appends double quote at the end of it which I don't want.The assigned array is following-

```
var array="[1,2,3,5]";
```

but I want the array will be like this-

```
var array=[1,2,3,5];
```

Comment: is it related to java or javascript ?

Comment: So you ask a question that make no sense and you answer it?

Comment: Your question needs work. As it stands, it's really unclear what the issue is. Consider including an [mcve] if possible that outlines your issue. Looking at this question, my immediate thought is, "well, remove the quotes from your code then", and I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: If It is about Javascript then use `JSON.parse(array)`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the square brackets out of the string and then you can use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to make it an array, and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to make it an array of integers:

```js
let str = "[1,2,3,5]"

str = str.substring(1, str.length-1) //remove first and last char ([ & ])

str = str.split(","); //make an array on every comma

str = str.map(x => parseInt(x)); //parse integers

console.log(str);
```

Alternatively you can use JSON.parse() to parse the array:

```js
let str = "[1,2,3,5]";

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `parse` the string. Your array was `JSON.stringify`'d. You can also do this with objects

```
var array="[1,2,3,5]";
array = JSON.parse(array);
console.log(array);
```